# How to create a generic function to extract data from nested object in desired format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

So, this is the example of data I am getting from somewhere. You can see that there are `buckets` fields (array). The buckets can be nested inside `buckets` too (array again) up to any level. For me the `key` of each level and `doc_count` of the last levels are important. I know the level of nesting (say, till 3, 5 or anything beforehand).

```
const obj= {
    "aggregations": {
      "1": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "2": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 3171,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "3": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "key": "demo_gg",
                        "doc_count": 856
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "key": "/hello",
                  "doc_count": 8888
                },
                {
                  "3": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "key": "bye",
                        "doc_count": 414
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "key": "added*",
                  "doc_count": 4987
                },
                {
                  "3": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "key": "nothere",
                        "doc_count": 118
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "key": "/festive.txt",
                  "doc_count": 1888
                }
              ]
            },
            "key": "200",
            "doc_count": 4771
          },
          {
            "2": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 536,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "3": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "key": "diemsion",
                        "doc_count": 1435
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "key": "/auto/auto.xml",
                  "doc_count": 1888
                },
                {
                  "3": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "key": "cartoon",
                        "doc_count": 34
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "key": "/.env",
                  "doc_count": 888
                },
                {
                  "3": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "key": "mouse",
                        "doc_count": 8
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "key": "/form/admin/login",
                  "doc_count": 888
                }
              ]
            },
            "key": "404",
            "doc_count": 2052
          }
        ]
      }
    } 
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[
  ['200', '/hello', 'demo_gg', 856],
  ['200', 'added*', 'bye', 414],
  ['200', '/festive.txt', 'nothere', 118],
  ['404', '/auto/auto.xml', 'dimension', 1435],
  ['404', '/.env', 'cartoon', 34],
  ['404', '/form/admin/login', 'mouse', 8]
]
```

*Note: There can be any level of nesting of buckets so likewise each array will increase horizontally. So, I need a general function for any level of nesting till it stops. Thanks.*

Comment: Frame challenge: where does your data originally come from (the source json)?   Might be easier to change the DB query to give you what you want up-front.

Comment: @freedomn-m, these are auto-generated logs